# onDraw get width of a drawn line

Tags: android, android-custom-view, ondraw

I think if it's possible to get the width of a drawn line in `onDraw` of a Custom View.I Want the width of **startX** line And **StopX** in Drawn Line

```
override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
    viewHeight = measuredHeight
    viewWidth = measuredWidth

 // I want the width of this line...
    canvas?.drawLine(0f,0f, (viewWidth/5).toFloat(),0f,paint)


    super.onDraw(canvas)
}
```

Thank you very much for your time and assistance in this matter.

Comment: [`Paint.getStrokeWidth()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#getStrokeWidth())

Answer (score 0):

You can use View.getWidth() and View.getHeight() because measurement already was finished. More: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View

[image]

Comment: no its not what i am looking for...i dont want view width i want start x and stop x in drawn line width

Comment: @docbigolo you can use View.getLeft() and View.getRight() if your want. But they returns the position of view relative to its parent. Method onDraw() is calling when measurement already was finished and getWidth() return the width of your item and getHeight() return the height of your item.